# ImportError: cannot import name 'SequentialFeatureSelector'

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector
```

When I import SequentialFeatureSelector from sklearn.feature_selection I get an import error

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'SequentialFeatureSelector'


sklearn.__version__
    -> 0.22.2.post1

    !pip3 install --upgrade
    -> Requirement already up-to-date: sklearn in /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.0)
-> Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scikit-learn in /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sklearn) (0.22.2.post1)
```

I seem to have the most up to date version of skikit learn. I think the problem has to do with the environment I'm coding in, I'm using Azure Machine Learning Notebooks. When I import the same class on google colab, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[`SequentialFeatureSelector`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelector.html), per `sklearn` documentation, was new in version `0.24`.

As you indicated, importing in [`Google Colab`](https://colab.research.google.com/?utm_source=scs-index) and it works would indicate `Google Colab` has a more updated version.

It doesn't seem like `pip` can hit `PyPi`, so there isn't much you can do outside of asking the administrators to upgrade the package.